# Convert Control to Bunifu Checkbox

Tags: c#, bunifu

I need to convert `often` to `Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox`
. my current code:

```
foreach (Control often in d.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox>())
{
  Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox Checkbox4 = often;
  //how can i make this work?

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast them as that specific type, like this:

```
Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox Checkbox4 = (Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox) often;
```

OR

```
Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox Checkbox4 = often as Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox;
```